# What should be done to ensure my ASP.NET MVC app can "talk" to a card reader via a USB port?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dllimport, smartcard

What should I done to enable my ASP.NET MVC app can "talk" to a card reader via a USB port? It worked with a desktop app and all I did was copy the dll file to a folder in the bin/Debug folder and do the necessary DllImport moves since it was written in C++ most likely.
With this desktop app I could write to the card, read it, reset it, etc.

I did the same [copy the dlls into the bin folder and fully referenced the dll in one of the controllers] all to no avail. I realize the MVC app runs inside a browser, so how do I go about implementing this scenario? Can I use a web service to expose the functionality of the desktop app? I have pasted part of the code here.

```
public class FrontDeskController : Controller
{
    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]
    [DllImport(@"C:\Users\charles\Documents\Visual Studio     2012\Projects\hotels\MvcXsoftHotelApp\bin\Debug\LevelLock.dll")]
    private static extern short LV3_BeepOk();           // Sound of success

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]
    [DllImport(@"C:\Users\charles\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\hotels\MvcXsoftHotelApp\bin\Debug\LevelLock.dll")]
    private static extern short LV3_InitializeSystem(short LockType);
```

Comment: Is the card reader attached to your server or are you expecting each client to have one connected to their PC?

Comment: For the meantime, I am trying to run it in VS2012 dev environment. However, in real life, the app should run on each client.

Comment: I understand that the app would run in the client's browser. That's the point of a web app. I'm asking where the actual card reader would be.

Comment: Then you're out of luck. Your MVC application never runs on the client at all. It runs on the server and produces HTML and script that runs on the client. Such script will never have access to the card reader in the general case. If you restrict yourself to browsers on computers owned by your company, then you could write an ActiveX control to do so.

Comment: Wow that's true. Okay what if the card reader will be installed on the server where the app is deployed? Is there any 'hope' apart from ActiveX? :)

Comment: On the server, there should be no problem, assuming the reader can be use from a desktop application. At worse, you would need to configure a higher trust level for the application.

Comment: If ActiveX is the way to go with this issue? Does anybody have a link where I can learn how to create an ActiveX control using VS2012 and C# and integrate it with an MVC app? The only ones I see showcase .vbp files. I would not mind if one of us provide the link as an answer to the question so I can mark it as answered. By the way why won't a Wcf web service app or library solve this problem? Just asking.

Comment: @Charles what kind of card reader? I've integrated a USB card swipe into a webpage, as swiping while the cursor is focused on a text box writes out the content just like if you typed in with a keyboard. Then I used javsacript to format/parse what was read.

Comment: The card reader is an MF1, PnP driver device. The card is placed on the device for reading/writing. The user clicks a button on the web page to issue a command and the result is expected. I guess it's way different than your device, Mike.

Comment: @Charles sounds like it!

Comment: Ok MikeSmithDev can you fill me in on how you went about retrieving what you read from the reader and how you made your reader accessible to the web page via javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer. I am sure StackOverflow came in somewhere in the mix. I cannot quote the post or question now but I have all the links that enabled Silverlight run inside a browser but under trusted privileges. Now Silverlight can both run inside the browser and access the USB card reader hardware on the client PC.
Here are the links

http://cureos.blogspot.com/2011/09/pinvoke-bundling-native-dlls-in.html?showComment=1393315645042#c1274996580196954353

https://github.com/cureos/nativedll/blob/master/NativeDllInvoker/NativeDllHelper.cs

http://www.mistergoodcat.com/post/Silverlight-5-Tidbits-Trusted-applications

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793(v=vs.96).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730989(WS.10).aspx

At least maf748's answer got me thinking in that direction. Thanks to the SO community!

Answer (score 2):

If Silverlight 4 is an option, you could create an out-of-browser application which would give you access to COM interop.

Comment: For now Silverlight 4 is not an option unless it can be integrated with an ASP.NET MVC application maybe as a tag on an html razor page. If you have a clue in form of a link or something please share. thanks.

Comment: I was also considering using WcfService Library to achieve this feat of talking to the card reader. The WcfService has a reference from a Windows Form project and I attempt to call methods in the windows form project class that talks to the card reader through P/Invoke in this my Web service. I am not sure what I am missing here though. I keep getting an error-Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail.

Comment: You can definitely host the silverlight app in a web app; in short, the app is downloaded from your web page, then the user gives it permission to run out-of-browser. I have used this in the past to interface with a local scanner and have the images uploaded to my webapp. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550721(v=vs.95).aspx#outofbrowser_install_launch_and_uninstall

Comment: Thanks maf748. I am using silverlight as an OOB app but i keep getting this error: Attempt by security transparent method 'SilverlightApp.MainPage.InitandReg()' to call native code through method 'SilverlightApp.MainPage.LV3_InitializeSystem(Int16)' failed.  Methods must be security critical or security safe-critical to call native code. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: I don't really have enough info to determine what is going on, but it sounds like it might not be properly configured for OOB. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833073(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: The error has stopped-it had to "Require elevated trust when running outside the browser" but in running out of browser it now looks like a different app altogether. I want it to still look like it's within the browser and not a separate app on its own with a shortcut on the desktop. Is that possible?

Comment: With SL4, it's not possible. I personally haven't done this w/ SL5, but this looks promising in an intranet environment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48149/discussion-between-charles-and-maf748)

Comment: I sincerely apologize for marking this as the answer. I had to unmark it because running as an OOB makes it look like a separate app which is NOT what i want. Besides someone else may have an input to make that will help me run the card access code in browser[not ActiveX] and still access COM or USB functionality of the client PC. I was hinted that Silverlight 5 can do it as an app whose certificate is in the local trusted store[which i have explored but still didn't work]. Has anyone actually achieved it among us?

Comment: I sincerely apologize for marking this as the answer. I had to unmark it because running as an OOB makes it look like a separate app which is NOT what i want. Besides someone else may have an input to make that will help me run the card access code in browser[not ActiveX] and still access COM or USB functionality of the clientPC.I was hinted that Silverlight 5 can do it as app whose certificate is in trusted store[which i have tried.Seems I missed something].Has anyone achieved it among us? One more thing...if I have to use ActiveX and build it into a cab file can I do this with MFC in VS2012?